# ajax cant' get response from res.send?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

My cilent side I do my ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'item/add',
  data: $(this).serialize()
}).done(function(data) {

  if (data.result === 1) {

  }

});
```

Then my node js I

```
router.post('item/add',function(){
//item model
..
..
res.send({result:1})
})
```

I expect the done() promise will get 1, but I'm seeing {result:1}, after that, it took over my entire screen. Why is it happending?

Comment: Try to set `dataType: 'json'` for the ajax request

Comment: Or `res.json(OBJECT)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny tried doesn't work. I can see the request is going well to my server.

Comment: @RayonDabre same problem.

Comment: It is not about request, it is about response.. Can you tell us `typeof data` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm seeing the correct response in the network tab of chrome inspection tool. I'm now suspecting it's a IOS chrome problem.

Comment: What does a relative path `router.post('item/add', ...)` mean on the server?  Relative to what?  In the client, that path is relative to the browser web page, but not on the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 are you saying I'm hitting the wrong endpoint?

Comment: I'm saying that you should not use relative paths when defining routes.  My guess for what's happening is in my answer below.

Comment: You are expecting response as __1__ but you are sending object as `{result:1}`

Comment: @RayonDabre - No, the OP is expecting `data.result === 1` which is consistent with `{result: 1}`.